# How to input or determine cluster center in k-means python?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, center, k-means, centroid

I have some problems with clustering method, that is K-Means
I want to cluster a new data with latitude and longitude coordinates. But before that, I have set the cluster center myself, with the existing data. Can anyone explain in python code how to input cluster center data into kmeans method without doing a fit to kmeans?
because when the existing data is fit to kmeans, the center of the cluster will change, so the new data will be based on the new cluster center obtained from the fitting results.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to just implement the kmeans prediction algorithm. Do you specifically need to use sklearn kmeans? After fitting you should be able to change the `model.cluster_centers_` but you would not be able to control the labels.